# Automatically add text to new file when in certain directory in GitHub's Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I've started using GitHub's Atom editor and it's billed as "A hackable text editor for the 21st century."

This, combined with a lot of me typing the same thing again and again recently, made me curious if it would be possible to customize/create a script that detects whatever directory the previously open file was in, and if it's a certain directory, adds certain text to the new file.

In this question, I'm using the example of creating a new file when I was previously editing a C++ file, so when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> it would create a new file with the text:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. How? Create a package that uses the Atom API.